# Ionic 3 Cannot find module "rxjs/operators/share"

Tags: rxjs, ionic3, translate

I'm using Ionic 3 to build an mobile application and everything is working fine, but when I add `@ngx-translate`, I got this error and I didn't find any solution for this issues

### ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/operators/share"
at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:159023)
at Object.<anonymous> (core.es5.js:3855)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4cdf06f8badf4bef7b37:54)
at Object.397 (main.ts:5)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4cdf06f8badf4bef7b37:54)
at Object.392 (main.js:852)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4cdf06f8badf4bef7b37:54)
at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 4cdf06f8badf4bef7b37:25)
at main.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

For me helps change the version of @ngx-translate/core to version: "7.2.2"

I've compare with working example of github repo of ngx-translate
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/examples/ionic/package.json

Change the version of @ngx-translate/core in you `package.json`

to `"@ngx-translate/core": "7.2.2",`

and run `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem just  few days back. What you need to do is uninstall the current @ngx-translate/core which version 9.0.2 by running this command `npm uninstall @ngx-translate/core --save` this will remove the module and also update your package.json file. now install the module again and specify the version number like this `npm install @ngx-translate/core@8.0.0 --save`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by your rxjs version. Please update it to the latest stable version and you shouldn't see this issue anymore.